# how to access data from nested DataFrame, python

Tags: python, dataframe, nested

I have a complex json file with 6 columns and 330MB in size. I have read it into a dataframe using

data=pd.read_json("nutrients.json", lines=True)

I have attached the structure of the json object below.

[Json structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfpCi.jpg)

[json strcture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFGnl.jpg)

i am having trouble with the resulting DataFrame. The "data" has 6 columns but there are not simple lists. they are dataFrames in itself. Like 'name', 'nutrients'.

I am having really hard time with manupulating this data. How can I access

data2= data[data['group']=='Cheese', ['name']]
this gives me 1 columns which is a dataframe of 3 fields within name. I want to get 3 columns with each name seperately?

I have tried using json_normalize() but its been excessively complex and didnt guve me any usable results.

please help

Comment: i have also tried using json_normalize() function but the object i read was already a DataFrame. when i manually try to add the json obkect into a list, the pc memory runs out. i managed to do it but json_normalize function still didnt worked & put everything in 1 column

Comment: Any inputs here please .....